# Using a custom header in android

Tags: android

I am using a custom header in android. The issue is when the activity loads up for about 1s the default brown/blackish header is shown. How do I prevent this from happening?

Relevant xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#00693331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">70dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

I am inflating the layout in java.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by initially setting the theme to:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

We set this for the whole application, then override it in the activities with our custom title bar theme.

Comment: Would it be possible to show a splash screen for some time and call the other activity which loads up in the background and then destroy the splash screen?

Comment: Yes, but that is different that just fixing the problem you are seeing.